# Confirm Email The provided anti-forgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin, csrf

**Situation**

I have been struggling with what appears to be a common error but it is affecting me differently.

I have an application where a registers an account and gets a verification link in their email and if they do not verify they of course cannot sign in.

**Problem**

What I have done is this, If a user that is signing in has NOT verified their account, then I take them to a page which says "Email is not confirmed confirm or please click here to resend the verification code".
When I click the "Resend verification code" button, I get the error

```
The provided anti-forgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user.
```

The code belowis the Login code, please pay attention to the if statement that redirects if the user is CORRECT but not confirme.

```
   public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
    // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

    if (result == SignInStatus.Success)
    {
        var userid = UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email).Id;
        if (!UserManager.IsEmailConfirmed(userid))
        {

            return RedirectToAction("EmailNotConfirmed", new {  model.Email });
        }
    }


    // If username and password is correct check if account is activated.
    ////if (!UserManager.IsEmailConfirmed(userid) && result == SignInStatus.Success)
    ////{
    ////    result = SignInStatus.RequiresVerification;
    ////}
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
    }
}
```

Below now is my `EmailNotConfirmed` method

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult EmailNotConfirmed(string email)
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
    Session.Abandon();

    LoginViewModel l = new LoginViewModel();
    l.Email = email;
    ViewBag.email = email;

    return View(l);
}
//
// POST: /Account/EmailNotConfirmed
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> EmailNotConfirmed(LoginViewModel model)
{
    Session.Abandon();
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut();

    var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };


    var locUser = from t in db.Users
                  where t.Email == model.Email
                  select new
                  {
                      t.Id
                  };
    var locId= locUser.Select(e => e.Id).FirstOrDefault();



    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
    // Send an email with this link
    string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(locId);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = locId, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(locId, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");

}
```

View

```
@model  ClientAccess.Models.LoginViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EmailNotConfirmed";
}




<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h5> Email not confirmed</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">

        <p> Your account is not confirmed, please visit your email to confirm your account or click the button below to resend your verification code</p>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("EmailNotConfirmed", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })


            <INPUT class="btn btn-success" name=SUBMIT type=submit value="Resend Verification Code">
        }

    </div>

    <p class="mb-2 text-muted">Already Verified? Login @Html.ActionLink("Here", "Login", "Account")</p>
</div>
```

In alot of questions I looked at adding
`Session.Abandon();
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut();` is normally the recommendation but as for me, this has not worked, appreciate if I could get some assistance in solving this.

Regards

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked with the antiforgery token, but I'm pretty sure that having `Session.Abandon()` in your POST method is wrong. Antiforgery token works by comparing two encrypted values with each other: one in the cookie and one in the session. So by abandoning the session, ASP.NET can't verify the token anymore.

Comment: @howcheng I commented it out. Still not working. But the reason behind me adding it is that. IF I attempt to sign in with an unverified account, logout, then request the verification, it work but if I dont log out, it doesnt work.

Comment: What if you move `AuthenticationManager.SignOut()` and `Session.Abandon()` to before you `return RedirectToAction("EmailNotConfirmed", new {  model.Email })`?